# ESLint Unexpected dangling '_' in '__place' no-underscore-dangle

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have the below JSON response, to validate the __place, i used responseData.search[0].edges[0].node.**__place**

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": [
      {
        "__place": "SearchResultItemConnection",
        "edges": [
          {
            "cursor": "New",
            "node": {
              "__place": "Delhi",
              "name": "AIIMS"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm getting the ESLint error stating **"error    Unexpected dangling '_' in '__typename'                                      no-underscore-dangle"**

I went through the link, http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle but i'm not able to resolve this.

Could anyone know how to resolve this, instead of changing the rules?

Comment: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle#when-not-to-use-it

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can add the following comment before the code line which yields the error:

```
/* eslint no-underscore-dangle: ["error", { "allow": ["__place"] }]*/
responseData.search[0].edges[0].node.__place
```

or add

```
/* eslint no-underscore-dangle: 0 */
```

to disable this specific rule for that script file.

Comment: Working fine. Thank you. My understanding about adding the line before the error code will disable the eslint no-underscore-dangle rule right?

Comment: `/* eslint no-underscore-dangle: 0 */` disables the rule for that file, while `/* eslint no-underscore-dangle: [1, { "allow": ["__place"] }]*/` still keeps the rule, but add the "name" __place to its exceptions list.

Answer (score 43):

You can simply exclude those by providing exceptions in the config file.

```
"no-underscore-dangle":  ["error", { "allow": ["_place"] }]
```

Comment: Definitely the best answer.  Littering your code with /* eslint disable */ rules makes for brittle coding standards because it always starts off with "we'll just disable this _one_ line" and then it ends up all over the place.

Comment: Very useful when dealing with mongodb objectId's `_id`

Answer (score 31):

In case you would like to disable a whole rule (for example "no-underscore-dangle"), just type in config :

```
{    
   rules: {        
      "no-underscore-dangle": 'off'
   },
};
```

Comment: A thread justifying why this rule is commonly turned off: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1024. It provides a useful hint you shouldn't touch something, helping people understand even though they know it's not truly private.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following above the line:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
```